# Does Task<T>.Result block if the task is Completed?

Tags: c#, task, blocking

Accessing the `Result` property of a task has the potential to block until the task is complete, as [Stephen Cleary's article on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) demonstrates.

I imagine that accessing `Result` on a task that has already completed will never block, but I have not been able to find any source that confirms that. Is that so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Task.Result Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> The get accessor for this property ensures that the asynchronous operation is complete before returning. Once the result of the computation is available, it is stored and will be returned immediately on later calls to Result.